# Вопросительные предложения без вопросительной интонации

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

О существовании вопросительно-утвердительных предложений всем известно. А существует ли такая единица, как вопросительное предложение, оформленное как повествовательное? Собственно, меня интересует не столько этот вопрос, сколько предложение "Что тут еще скажешь". Оно уже утратило цель высказывания, но мне неизвестно, по-прежнему ли оно оформляется как самостоятельная синтаксическая единица, или перешло в разряд вводных предложений. Если не перешло, какой знак ставится в конце? Вопросительный знак или многоточие?

Заблаговременно благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Выражение "Что тут скажешь" можно считать риторическим вопросом и оформлять соответствующим образом (вопросительный или восклицательный знак). В то же время по значению оно приближено к вводному предложению  и реально оформляется самыми различными способами: включается или не включается в предложение, используются различные знаки, в том числе запятая, многоточие.

Ну не повезло — что тут ещё скажешь? Мастер, что тут скажешь!

Это шедевр шедевров, что тут еще скажешь. Талант, что тут еще сказать. Разочарованы, что тут еще сказать...

Что тут скажешь, человеческие отношения сходят на нет. - Что тут еще сказать? - задал риторический вопрос Мазин.

2) Интересно сравнить "что тут скажешь" со сходным выражением "как знать", которое фактически является вводным словом.

Прощай, Русь! Как знать — не навсегда ли?

Как знать! Государь милостив и, главное, человек редкой, высокой души!

Как знать, быть может, я сделал бы то же самое!

Answer (score 0):

Больше всего понравилось "заблаговременно благодарю". ))))

При чем тут вводное предложение... Видите – ставлю многоточие. А мог бы и вопросительный.

У вас можно вопрос, можно многоточие, можно даже точку. У меня точку – плоховато выйдет.

Comment: В  собственных записках Вы можете ставить любые знаки, какие Вам нравятся. Но здесь речь идет об официальных правилах. У Вас есть ссылка на правило, в котором указано, что при наличии вопросительного местоимения можно ставить не только вопросительный/восклицательный знак, но и точку или многоточие.

Comment: А это жестко регламентировано? Ну, тогда авторы вовсю нарушают правила. Предложения типа "что тут ещё скажешь" лично мне неоднократно попадались и с вопросительным, и с многоточием, и с точкой.

Comment: В правописании все регламентировано. Если используется несоответствующий знак, то должна быть названа грамматическая форма,  которая этому знаку соответствует. Например, это не вопрос, а вводная конструкция.